# Go Tour Exercise #7: closing the channel

Tags: go

There's an [exercise](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/8) about binary tree in the Go tour.

I have solved this question already and some questions came up on the way.

here is the struct of tree

```
type Tree struct {
    Left  *Tree
    Value int
    Right *Tree
}
```

here's some code

```
//send values into channel
func Walk(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int){
    if t.Left != nil{
        Walk(t.Left, ch)
    }
    ch <- t.Value 
    if t.Right != nil{
        Walk(t.Right,ch)
    }
        
    //close(ch) will trigger a warning: close of a closed channel
}

//get values from channel
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 10)
    go Walk(tree.New(1),ch)

    //for i:=0;i<10;i++{  // This line works.
    for i:= range ch{     // This line doesn't,
                          // it reads infinitely from ch.
        println(i)  
    }
}
```

My question is in the main function it clearly shows that `ch` didn't get closed then why can't i close the channel in the Walk function?

Comment: The answer from mazei513 explains it very well: Your code recurses down and the moment you hit the first leaf you close the channel which is far too early. You should close the channel once after walking the _root_ of the tree only. A simple trick is to add a `WalkRoot` which just calls Walk and then closes the channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the function is recursive, and as such, every call of `Walk` will reach the line to close the channel, and each of them will try to close the channel. Thus any one of them that tries to close the channel after the first one will be trying to close a closed channel.